# Linux script for determining filesize

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a script to imitate this script output in linux bash:

```
(bob@server:~> filesize

Enter a file name (or q! to stop): fee

fee uses 123 bytes.

Enter a file name (or q! to sp): fi

There is no file called fi.

Enter a file name (or q! to stop): foe

foe uses 9802 bytes.

Enter a file name (or q! to stop): q!

bob@server:~>)
```

My script looks like this (the script name is filesize):

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
        read  -p "Enter a filename (Or q! to stop) : " X
        case $X in
                [q!]* ) exit;;
                * ) echo "$X uses "$(wc -c <$X)" bytes";./filesize;;
        esac
done
```

After I type anything other than `q!` and it reads `$X` uses `$(wc -c <$X)`, I have to type `q!` twice to make the command exit.

How do I make it so that I only have to type `q!` once to make the command exit, instead of typing it the multiple times that I read a size of a file?

Comment: Noobs (sorry if you aren't one) always want to read input interactively, which is usually a horrible idea... Learn how to use command line arguments and write scripts that can be piped up. That said, the reason is you have a redundant self-call `./filesize` in your script, which is pointless. You're already in a infinite loop until you break out. Just remove that.

Comment: The problem with `[q!]` is that it matches a *single* character which is either `q` or `!`.

Answer (score 3):

```
filesize(){ stat -c %s -- "$@";}
```

And if you insist on having all the blabber around it:

```
filesize(){ stat -c %s -- "$@";} 
while :; do
    read  -p "Enter a filename (Or q! to stop) : " x
    case "$x" in
        'q!') exit;;
       *) printf '%s\n' "$x uses $(filesize "$x") bytes";;
    esac
done
```

The function alone is much more Unix philophy than the while loop, however.

`wc -c < "$x"` is OK too. The difference is that `stat` will tell you the size right away without having to do the counting.

Comment: This is great! thank you, but after the command prints out the size of the file in bytes, when it reads "Enter a filename (or q! to stop) : again, it doesn't print on the next line. How would I edit the script to print on the next line?

Comment: The `'%s\n'` instead of `'%s'` should fix that. Sorry about that. I didn't test it. Printf gives you more robustness over `echo` in cases where the filename starts with a hyphen.

Comment: The pattern `[q!]*` doesn't really do what OP thinks it does. I'd suggest that you not reproduce the error.

Comment: @rici, Instead of just saying "_The pattern `[q!]*` doesn't really do what OP thinks it does. I'd suggest that you not reproduce the error._", it would be much more helpful if you'd either explain what is wrong with it and or suggest what is should be.  Thanks.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks. Made it correspond with the message. OP may feel free to a question about them shell patterns if he feels like it.